# wp_nav_menu li item empty

Tags: menus

I created an menu by admin panel > Appearence > Menu. I have just one menu page 
in **menu_lateral_1** .

Or the result is

```
<li id="menu-menu_lateral_1" class="menu"></li>
<li id="menu-item-212" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-212"><a href="my_website">my page</a></li>
```

With following code :

```
    $args = array(
        'menu' => 'menu_lateral_1',
        'container' => '',
        'items_wrap' => '<li id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</li>'
);
wp_nav_menu($args);
```

I don't understand where the first item comes ?!

Comment: Are you sure you gave the menu the position it has on the frontend? What happens is you add a custom link to an external website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Codex documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu). The `items_wrap` attribute is for wrapping the list elements as a whole - not each individual menu item:

> Whatever to wrap the items with an ul, and how to wrap them with

If you look at this [line](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L226) you'll see that it is using `sprintf` to replace three place-holders in the provided `items_wrap`. The first being an ID, the second a class, and lastly the items.

Try:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'menu' => 'menu_lateral_1', 
    'items_wrap' => '<ul id=\"%1$s\" class=\"%2$s\">%3$s</ul>' 
  ) ); ?>
```

This should give:

```
<ul id="menu-menu_lateral_1" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-212" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-212"><a href="my_website">my page</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Note:** [You should use `theme_location` rather than `menu`.](http://make.wordpress.org/themes/2012/03/16/custom-menus-implementation-use-theme_location-instead-of-menu-in-wp_nav_menu/)